# What Activation Function is appropriate for input range (0,1) and output range (-∞,∞) for Regression Nerwork in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

input images are regularized to (0, 1)
and output is float32 values having pseudo gaussian distribution (-∞,∞)

when fitted, both train and validation accuracy says over 0.999
but when predict using train and validation set, it does not reproduce itself.

predicted output shows only negative values( and few positive identical values )

is this problem caused by wrong selection of activation function?

i have tried, instead of 'relu', 'linear', 'sigmoid' too.
the results was same.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution1D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, input_shape=(img_width, img_height)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(2)))

model.add(Convolution1D(filters=32, kernel_size=2))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0001), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Prediction done like this,

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=2,
          validation_data=(x_valid, y_valid),
          batch_size=2048,
          shuffle='batch',
          use_multiprocessing=True)
# right after fitting 
result = model.predict(x_train, use_multiprocessing=True)
```

Comment: This is a regression problem, accuracy is a classification metric, it makes no sense to use accuracy for regression. You shoud look only to the loss or use mae as a metric

Comment: The problem was empty or non-sense data points in the dataset. I have eliminated them and it does reproduces, partially though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's extremely hard to design a model to output in such a big range, the error rate of the model will be extremely high.

1. I suggest you normalize your outputs in range (0., 1.) and use sigmoid in the last layer.

You can always use an inverse transform to reconstruct the original outputs.

```
mn = np.min(y_train)
mx = np.max(y_train)
y_train = (y_train - mn)/(mx - mn)

# ... train

# inverse transform
y_train_original = y_train*(mx-mn) + mn
```

> when fitted, both train and validation accuracy says over 0.999 but when 
>   predict using train and validation set, it does not reproduce itself.

reason: overfitting. your data is impossible to learn with such complex output distribution, so the model just blindly memorizes the training data without learning any patterns.

to avoid :

- use output normalizing.
- `model.add(Dense(256))` - reduce number of neurons here, try with `32->64->128`
- use dropout

Comment: It's not the solution for my problem, but chosen as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Convolution1D are not the standard choice to deal with images, I suggest you Convolution2D

Secondly, 'accuracy' is not the correct metric for regression task, good choice are mean squared error (mse), mean absolute error (mae), root mean squared error (rmse)

Answer (score 1):

> when fitted, both train and validation accuracy says over 0.999 but
>   when predict using train and validation set, it does not reproduce
>   itself.

This suggests something is going wrong with your prediction code, which you have not included. Either something wrong with your testing data or the way you are predicting (not loading weights?)

Comment: please add code for your data as well, are you regularizing test input 0-1 as well?

Comment: yes, as you can see from the code, i just used x_train again for the prediction. x_train is same with the variable for fitting.
data loaded using HDF5Matrix(keras utils) with normalization with 'lambda x: x/255.0'

Comment: I just noticed your batch size is 2048. That's very large and could cause problems, generally best practice is 32 or 64 for batch size.

Comment: Same weird result with batch size 32. I guess, input range [0, 1] and output range (-∞, ∞) mismatch with the training network. it looks like rectified. Should i regularize the output(y_train) in range [0, 1] too?